# Speed at which hands of clock approaching one another.

Tags: geometry, derivatives

A clock's hour hand's length is $1$, and its minute hand's length is $r$.
First I had to find the distance between the tips of the hands at 4:00. I did this using the law of cosines. This gives me $(r^2 + r + 1)^{1/2}$. Now I have to find the speed at which the tips of the hands are approaching one another at 4:00.

I know that the speed of the hour hand is $π/6$ per hour and the speed of the minute hand is $2π$ per hour.

The distance between the tips of the hands at a given moment:
$d(t) = (1 + r^{2} - 2r\cos(a(t)))^{1/2}$

where $a(t)$ is the angle between the two hands at the given moment.
Am I supposed to calculate the derivative of that? If so, what is the best way to calculate the derivative for something this complex?

Comment: Do you know the chain rule?

Comment: Do you have an explicit formula for $a(t)$?

Comment: I do know the chain rule but when I did it for this I didn't get the same answer that wolframalpha gives. Maybe it was simply some "silly error" of mine.

Comment: $a(0)$ $=$ $2π$ $-$ $π/6$ $=$ $11π/12$ ... I should probably use that to get a "general formula". Trying that now. Or do I even need to do that since I want the velocity when $t$ $=$ $0$? So isn't it fine to just have $a(0)$?

Comment: @mangopancake, actually what you just found is the *derivative* of $a$, which is constant.

Comment: But of course! So I need to integrate it to get a(t) and substitute it into the equation for distance and differentiate that?

Comment: @mangopancake, something like that.  But you're really making it more complicated than it needs to be.  Each hand is moving at a constant angular rate, so the angle between them is a *linear* function of time, hence of the form $a(t)=mt+b$.  The coefficient $m$ is just the difference of the angular speeds, and $b$ is the angle between the two hands when $t=0$ (which, as you've done, you might as well take to be 4:00).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$$\begin{align}
d^2=1+r-2r\cos a(t)&\implies 2dd'=(2r\sin a(t))a'(t)\\
&\implies d'(t)={a'(t)r\sin a(t)\over d(t)}
\end{align}$$

Comment: What is this "method" called? If it is indeed a method.. Or is there a general formula for it or something? I'm having trouble figuring out where it comes from or how I would know that I need to use it.